# IE and Chrome not loading web pages

Tags: windows, windows-7, internet, troubleshooting

I have a laptop running `Windows 7 x86` on our network where `IE` and `Chrome` are not loading websites. The internet is working fine with other services. `Skype` and `Lync` work, and I can ping web addresses such as `baidu.com` successfully.

I have tried to `telnet` into websites using:

```
telnet baidu.com 80
```

but I get no messages other than a blank `cmd` window.

The user of the laptop does not have admin privileges and this issue happened 'suddenly' a couple of weeks ago.

Personally I suspect it is a firewall issue but cannot see why the firewall would have changed. I added port 80 as both an inbound and outbound rule, but still the browsers are not loading the web pages.

A virus scan a week back picked up some viruses and cleaned them off, so perhaps this has something to do with it?

Comment: Why bother troubleshooting? Just re-install with your image. Should be back up and running in an hour...

Comment: @EEAA That is an option. I would like to find out why though, and I'm not in the office that often.

Answer (score 1):

> A virus scan a week back picked up some viruses and cleaned them off,
>   so perhaps this has something to do with it?

It's probably rootkitted / bootkitted to hell and back.  All the classiest virusses drop them these days and they can do damn weird things to the networking subsystem.  Wipe and reload.

Answer (score 0):

Check the proxy settings under internet connection settings.

Comment: The proxy settings are the same as other PCs on the network

Comment: Try 'telnet google.com 80<enter> get / http/1.0<enter><enter>'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by:

1. Settings the DNS to [Google's Public DNS Servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)
2. Flushing the DNS settings as stated [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/problem-with-windows-7-starter-autoconfiguration/443696f3-52b6-476e-b6fc-e18f74f9d8b4):

> Type netsh winsock reset in the Command Prompt , and then press the Enter key.
>
> Do the same process for refreshing the TCP/IP just replace the typed command with.
>
> netsh interface ipv4 reset   press Enter
>
> netsh interface ipv6 reset   press Enter
>
> ipconfig /flushdns   press Enter

Answer (score 0):

+1. Works nicely

Type netsh winsock reset in the Command Prompt , and then press the Enter key.

Do the same process for refreshing the TCP/IP just replace the typed command with.

netsh interface ipv4 reset press Enter

netsh interface ipv6 reset press Enter

ipconfig /flushdns press Enter

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.